# ¿Cómo visualizar la vista del error 500 en un laravel dockerizado cuando se encuentra dentro de un proxy Nginx?

Tags: laravel, nginx, proxy, error500

Tengo una serie de aplicaciones Laravel 9.0 que funcionan correctamente. Cuando la aplicación se encuentra en un servidor con apache y, por cuestiones de testeos, quiero forzar un error 500, por ejemplo haciendo algo por el estilo:

```
$var = null;
echo $var->forzar_error;
```

El laravel muestra la vista blade que he definido en resources/views/errors/500.blade.php.

Sin embargo, he configurado un proxy con nginx y cuando con la misma aplicación fuerzo el error por cuestiones de testeos no hace el despliegue de la vista de Laravel, sino que muestra un error 500 genérico del explorador web que esté utilizando.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que en un proxy Nginx muestre, como en un nginx normal o como en apache, el error 500 de la vista de Laravel? ¿Requiero alguna configuración especial?

Comment: Nginx tiene una clave error_page en la que indicas el número de error y la localización de la página a mostrar. Mira el ejemplo en este artículo https://www.tecmint.com/create-custom-nginx-error-page/. Recuerda que los 500 son errores de servidor, por lo que no podrás llamar a tu Lara el para que renderice una página generica

Comment: Laravel tiene un catch de errores que cuando detecta un 500 muestra una vista determinada y manda como cabecera el error 500. Y eso me funciona bien en todos lados, en cualquier ambiente de producción menos cuando uso Nginx como un reverse proxy. Entiendo que Nginx detecta esa cabecera y quita a la aplicación de lado y decide por sí mismo lanzar el error que el quiere pero yo necesito que sea el propio contenedor el que gestione.
Buen artículo pero no me sirve ya que no solamente tengo una aplicación en ese servidor y cada error 500 debe ser personalizado para cada una de mis aplicaciones.

Comment: Voy a probar mañana hacer que no se mande la cabecera 500 a ver qué ocurre.